# Spring Security 6 - ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider doesn't throw an exception for invalid password in multi providers setup

Tags: spring-security

I want to create a login page where i first start with kerberos ticket validation and if that fails I want to do Active Directory login.
My security configuration is as follows

```
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.sun.GlobalSunJaasKerberosConfig;
import org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.sun.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationFailureHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;
import intauth.service.LdapUserDetailsService;

import java.io.IOException;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private LdapUserDetailsService ldapUserDetailsService;

    @Value("${app.service-principal}")
    private String servicePrincipal;

    @Value("${app.ad-domain}")
    private String adDomain;

    @Value("${ldap.url}")
    private String ldapUrl;

    @Value("${ldap.search.base}")
    private String ldapSearchBase;

    @Value("${ldap.base-user.principal}")
    private String baseUserPrincipal;

    @Value("${ldap.base-user.password}")
    private String baseUserPassword;

    @Value("${ldap.search.memberOf}")
    private String memberOfFilter;

    @Value("${app.keytab-location}")
    private String keytabLocation;

    @Value("${app.krb-conf-location}")
    private String krbConfLocation;

    @Value("${app.sun-jaas-kerberos-config-debug}")
    private boolean sunJaasKerberosConfigDebug;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
             .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .requestMatchers("/actuator/**",
                "/api/jwks/jwks.json",
                "/favicon.ico",
                "/login",
                "/error").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(spnegoEntryPoint())
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/actlogin").permitAll()
                .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider())
            .addFilterBefore(spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter(authenticationManager()),
            BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {

        KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider
            = kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider();
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider = activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider();
        return new ProviderManager(kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider
            , activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider
        );
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomSpnegoEntryPoint spnegoEntryPoint() {
        return new CustomSpnegoEntryPoint("/login");
    }

    @Bean
    public KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider() {
        KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider provider = new KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setTicketValidator(sunJaasKerberosTicketValidator());
        provider.setUserDetailsService(ldapUserDetailsService);
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider adLdapProvider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider( adDomain, ldapUrl);
        adLdapProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        adLdapProvider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        return adLdapProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomSpnegoFilter spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
        AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {

        CustomSpnegoFilter filter = new CustomSpnegoFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        filter.setFailureHandler(new AuthenticationFailureHandler() {
            @Override public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException exception)
                throws IOException, ServletException {
                response.sendRedirect("/actlogin");
            }
        });
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    public SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator sunJaasKerberosTicketValidator() {
        SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator ticketValidator = new SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator();
        ticketValidator.setServicePrincipal(servicePrincipal);
        ticketValidator.setKeyTabLocation(new FileSystemResource(keytabLocation));
        ticketValidator.setDebug(true);
        return ticketValidator;
    }

    @Bean
    public GlobalSunJaasKerberosConfig globalSunJaasKerberosConfig() {
        GlobalSunJaasKerberosConfig globalSunJaasKerberosConfig = new
            GlobalSunJaasKerberosConfig();
        globalSunJaasKerberosConfig.setDebug(sunJaasKerberosConfigDebug);
        globalSunJaasKerberosConfig.setKrbConfLocation(krbConfLocation);
        return globalSunJaasKerberosConfig;
    }

}
```

Based on the above when Kerberos fails, the user is redirected to the formlogin page. User enters credentials and:

- If credentials are correct everything is fine
- If username or password is not correct (not in ldap) then an exception is not thrown from ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider :

```
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /actlogin
ctiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider : Authentication for testusername@testdomain.gr failed:javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090439, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v4563 ]
ctiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider : Active Directory authentication failed: Supplied password was invalid
intauth.util.LdapUtil                : Validating with ldap: ldaps://ldap1.testdomain.gr:3269 ldaps://ldap2.testdomain.gr:3269
intauth.util.LdapUtil                : Validating with windows user: testusername@testdomain.gr
intauth.util.LdapUtil                : Ldap filter : (userPrincipalName=testusername@testdomain.gr)
intauth.exception.LdapUserNotFoundException: User=testusername@testdomain.gr not found in ldap
```

But from the LdapUtil which is called from the UserDetailsService:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import intauth.util.LdapUtil;

@Component
@Configuration
public class LdapUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LdapUtil.class);

    @Value("${app.ad-domain}")
    private String domain;

    @Autowired
    private LdapUtil ldapUtil;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        String finalUsername = username.indexOf("\\") > -1 ? username.substring(username.indexOf("\\")+1) :
            username;

        finalUsername = finalUsername.indexOf("@") > -1 ? finalUsername : finalUsername+"@"+domain;

        intauth.entity.User user = ldapUtil.getUserRolesInLdap(finalUsername);
        log.info("User name: {}", finalUsername);
        return User.builder().username(username.split("@")[0]).authorities(user.getRoles()).password("******").build();
    }
}
```

If I increase logging to TRACE is see why this is happening. It is because ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider doesn't throw an exception so afterwards DaoAuthenticationProvider is called:

```
 ctiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider : Active Directory authentication failed: Supplied password was invalid
 **o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with DaoAuthenticationProvider (1/1)**
 ote.intauth.util.LdapUtil                : Validating with ldap: ldaps://ldap1.testdomain.gr:3269 ldaps://ldap2.testdomain.gr:3269
```

which in the event of a missing username throws the correct exception but for an incorrect password fails because ActiveDirecotry passwords cannot be retireved from AD to be validated and so I get a PasswordEncoder error (because passowrd retireved from ldap is missing).

I am not managing passowrd in any case and i see the problem is that ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider doesn't throw an exception that is managed from spring.

I'm trying with small security configuration changes but cannot get it to work.
I found in StackOverflow that the ldapUserDetailsService is autoinjecting the DaoAuthenticationProvider so
I also tried not Autowiring the LdapUserDetailsService in the configuration but take it from the application context inside the kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider bean but with no luck.

Any suggestion would be much appreciated.